# Blank output for an ASP.NET NUnit test application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nunit, nunit-3.0

I am currently working with [NUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NUnit) to write test cases for an ASP.NET application.

I have created a sample test project and have added NUnit latest version (3.6.1) and NUnitTestAdapter 2.1.1.

If I run the application by clicking on menu *Test* → *Windows* → *Text Explorer*, I am getting a blank screen in the *Output Window*. Why?

My code is:

```
[TestFixture]
public class SampleTest
{
    [Test]
    public void StringCheck()
    {
        string str = "Hello";
        Assert.That(str, Is.EqualTo("Hello"));
    }

    [Test]
    public void EmptyCheck()
    {
        string str = "siva";

        Assert.That(str, Is.EqualTo(string.Empty));
    }

    [Test]
    public void NumberCheck()
    {
        int i = 0;
        Assert.That(i, Is.EqualTo(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: (If it is for emphasis, we have ***bold*** and *italics* on ***this platform***.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was with NUnit version (3.6.1). Now I am updated with NUnit 2.6.4. It is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the adapter for the NUnit 2.x series, rather than the NUnit 3 adapter. NUnit versions 2 and 3 differ substantially, and there are two separate Visual Studio adapters to run the tests.

This is the one you'll need to run NUnit 3.6.1 tests:

*[NUnit 3 Test Adapter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NUnitDevelopers.NUnit3TestAdapter)*